# escape an iframe based on whether the users mouse is over the iframe window

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

if the iframe window displayed is being seen then there is no problem but if the iframe window is set with 0px X 0px just to hide the iframe but load it, then redirect the iframe or not show it at all.

Also if something is loaded in an iframe or frame how can it be broken out of generally? I would use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.clientWidth` and `window.clientHeight` to check the size of the window. If it's too small, break out using  `top.location = self.location.href`.

Comment: can you please give a bit of js...sorry if its too much to ask for but I am a complete noob at this stuff. thanks